# Is it possible to have a compiler which optimizes a = func(a)?

Tags: compiler-optimization

Say I have an object of type A. Consider this case for any function of the type A -> A (i.e. takes object of type A and returns another object of type A):

```
foo = func(foo)
```

Here, the simplest case would be to for the result of `func(foo)` to be copied into `foo`.
Is it possible to optimize this so that:

- `foo` gets modified inplace in `func`

There are no constraints on the language used. What I want to know is what constraints and properties the language must have to enable such an optimization. Are there any existing languages which perform such an optimization?

Example(in pseudo code):

```
type Matrix = List<List<int>>

Matrix rotate90Deg(Matrix x):
   Matrix result(x.columns, x.rows) #Assume it has a constructor which takes as args the num of rows, and num of cols.
   for (int i = 0; i < x.rows; i++):
       for (int j = 0; j < x.columns; j++):
           result[i][j] = x[j][i]
   return result

Matrix a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
a = rotate90Deg(a)
```

Here, is it possible to optimize the code so that it doesn't allocate memory for a new matrix(result), and instead just modifies the original matrix passed.

Comment: Sure, when you inline function call you can do that and much more.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how inline functions can help make a function inplace? Thank you.

Comment: Consider `func(x) = x * 2` and code `foo = func(foo)`. After inlining it's `foo = foo * 2` and on common processors can be realized with single instruction like `ADD r1, r1`. It's also possible in more complex cases, especially if address of `foo` doesn't ["escape"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_analysis).

Comment: In C-like languages, func can take a pointer to foo, operate on foo and write back to foo directly. `void func(int* foo) { (*foo) += 10; }`. C# does the same with `ref` parameters. Is this what you're getting at?

Comment: @antiduh no that's not what I mean. I edited the question and added an example.

Comment: Inlining a call is the type of thing that optimizing compilers do all the time, and that "exposes" lots of optimizations.  There is some potential that a compiler in, say, a "matrix rich" language might look for cases where the same matrix is source and target of a call and eliminate temps, but in the above case the temp is needed to prevent destructive modification of the source while updating the target.

Comment: @HotLicks, that is exactly my question. While it may be possible to create optimizations for particular data structures, is there a way to generalize such optimizations for all data structures. Maybe by enforcing some constraints on the language?

Comment: Well, there's quite a bit of speculation there.  And compiler writers generally write with a given set of problems (often derived from statistical measures) in mind, vs attacking "theoretical" optimization issues.  So I would say "possible", but "not likely".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you have to realize that some operations are inherently not possible to be computed in-place. Matrix-matrix multiplication is an example of this, and `rotate90Deg` would fall under this category since such an operation is actually a matrix multiplication by the appropriate multiplication matrix.

Now as for your example, you actually coded up a *matrix transpose* function. Matrix transpose can be done in-place since you are swapping pairs of numbers, but I doubt that any compilers can automatically detect this and optimize it for you. Indeed, there are many, many tricks that one can do to optimize matrix transpose in order to be cache-friendly in order to gain huge performance increases. Nevertheless, with an naive implementation, you will almost certainly end up with something very similar to what Aditya Kumar describes in his answer.

---

As I have foreshadowed by using the word "naive" earlier, programmers can coax the compiler to inline lots and lots of things in extremely optimized ways through advanced templating and other meta-programming techniques. (At least in C++, and maybe other languages that allow you to overload `operator =`.) For anyone interested in a case study of how this is done and what is involved, take a look at the [Eigen matrix library](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicInsideEigenExample.html), and how it handles a simple operation like `u = v + w;` where the three variables are all matrices of floats. Following is a brief overview of the key points.

A naive implementation would overload `operator+` to return a temporary and `operator=` to copy that temporary to the result. Of course, in C++11 it is pretty easy to avoid the final copy during assignment by way of move constructors, but you will still have unnecessary temporaries if you had something a little more complex with multiple operators on the right hand side like `u = 3.15f * u.transposed() + 5.0f;` since each operator/method would return a temporary, and that temporary would have to be looped over in order to process the next operator.

**Long story short**, what Eigen does is rather than perform each operation when the corresponding function call occurs, the calls return a templated functor of sorts which merely *describes* the operation that needs to take place, and all the actual work ends up happening in `operator =`, thus enabling the compiler to emit a single, inlined loop for traversing the data only once and doing the operation truly in-place.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, and this optimization is provided by at least C++11 (inlining).

To explain the optimization a little bit.

e.g.

```
foo_t foo;
foo = func(foo); // #1
foo_t func(foo_t foo1) {
   foo_t new_foo;
   // operate on new_foo by using foo1
   return new_foo;
}
```

There are three instances of `foo_t` being made:

1. `foo` is copied and passed as `foo1` to `func`
2. `new_foo` is created.
3. `new_foo` is assigned to `foo` by copying the contents of `new_foo` into `foo`;

All the three copies can be eliminated provided there are some invariants.

1. `foo` (the argument to be passed to function is never used later with the same original value. This is equivalent to saying that `foo` is 'dead' at line #1. This is established here as `foo` is reassigned.
2. the scope of object `new_foo` in function `func` has its lifetime that does not extend the life of function `func`. This is also established here as the way `new_foo` is created, it will be on stack and the lifetime of objects in stack is the same as the lifetime of the function in which the object was created.

In C++ it can be achieved using inlining the function `func`. After inlining, the code basically will look like this.

```
`foo_t foo;`
`foo_t new_foo;`
`// operate on new_foo by using foo`
`foo = new_foo;`
```

Although, C++ provides inlining as a language feature but almost any optimizing compiler do inlining these days.

Now it depends on what kind of operation you perform on `new_foo` and `foo` whether this extra `new_foo` will be optimized away or not. For some data types it is trivial (the compiler can do a 'copy-propagation' followed by 'dead-code elimination' to remove `new_foo` completely.

Comment: In the above example the temporary object cannot be eliminated because the source and destination are the same.  To modify the destination destroys the source.

Comment: @HotLicks, You are right. I have removed the references to move-semantics.